# Loopback validation on Properties whose types are other Models

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

I have two Models defined; Location and Address, defined as follows:

```
"address": {
    "properties": {
        "address1": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "db",
    "plural": "addresses"
},  
"location": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "address":{
            "type": "address",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "db",
    "plural": "locations"
}
```

When I Create an object based on the *address* Model via the API Explorer, the *required* constraint on *address1* behaves as expected and I must supply a value to create the object.

When I Create an object based on the *location* Model via the API Explorer, the *required* constraint on the *address* works as expected, but the *required* constraint on the *address1* of the *address* Model does not.  I am able to create an address without an address1, which is not what I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong or is validation only performed on the root object?

I am using a memory datasource, node v0.10.24 and loopback v1.8.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, validations only happen at root level. Can you open an issue at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler?

BTW, I recommend you post questions to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs for prompt responses.

Comment: Is this still the case in the newer version?

Comment: I would also be interested to hear the status of this.