# Loopback validation on Properties whose types are other Models (version 2.xx)

Tags: loopbackjs

NOTE: This is kind of a duplicate of [Loopback validation on Properties who's types are other Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161921/loopback-validation-on-properties-whos-types-are-other-models) but I am re-asking because a lot of changes were made in Loopback 2

I have a Model (Vehicle) that has properties that are object with some data that needs to be validated.

Here is a sample vehicle

```
{

    details : {
        year : 2007,
        make: 3333,
        ....
    },
    options : {
        hasAirbags: true,
        powerWindows : false,
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

I have defined my models as such

```
"vehicleDetails": {
    "properties": {
        "year": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "db",
    "plural": "addresses"
},  
"Vehicle": {
    "properties": {
        "options": {
            "type": "vehicleOptions"
        },
        "details":{
            "type": "vehicleDetails"
        }
    },
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "db",
    "plural": "locations"
}
```

However, when I create a vehicle. it doesn't check to see if the details object I pass is valid. Relationship between vehicle and vehicleDetails is one-to-one, so I don't want to separate them with relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this little work around, but it seems like it should be simpler than this. I am trying to validate that the `address` property of an account is a valid `Address` model.

```
  Account.validate('address', function (err) {
    var Address = Account.app.models.Address;
    var address = new Address(this.address);
    address.isValid(function (valid) {
      if (valid === false) {
        err();
      }
    });
  }, {
    message: 'Address is not valid'
  });
```